# read number from cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to register how many times a song has been played. I got this working, but I don't want this amount of times to be reset when the browser is closed. I tried working with cookies, but was not able to figure that out.

Looking forward to your replies!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Showcase Titou Brouwers</title>

  <meta charset ="UTF-8">   
</head>
<body>

  <audio id="music" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" onended="yourFunction()">
    <source src="Data/1.mp3" type="audio/mp3"  />
  </audio>

<script src="App.js"></script>

  <p>Total amount of sessions: </p>
  <p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Javscript

```
//if music ends perform addSession
document.querySelector("#music").addEventListener("ended", addSession, false);

//Create cookie
document.cookie = "totalSessionsJ=0";
var totalSessions = document.cookie;
console.log(totalSessions);
//Increase totalSessions variable with 1
function addSession () {
  document.cookie = totalSessions + 1;

  //Display amount of performed sessions
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = totalSessions;
}
//Display 0 when no sessions have been performed yet
//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 0;


/*
//If music ends perform yourFunction
document.querySelector("#music").addEventListener("ended", yourFunction, false);
//Let box pup-up in which you can type the score you give your session
function yourFunction () {
prompt('How many stars of five do you give this session?');

}
*/
```

EDIT

Now, I have the following, but I'm having difficulty adding 1 to the the cookie value. Also, the last line of code doesn't want to work.

```
//Create cookie
document.cookie = "totalSessionsJ=0; expires=Sun, 28 May 2028 12:00:00 UTC";

function getCookieVal() {
    var cookieValue = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)totalSessionsJ\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
    return cookieValue;
}

//Increase totalSessions variable with 1
function addSession () {
var test = getCookieVal() + 1;
console.log(test);
  document.cookie = "totalSessionsJ = test; expires=Sun, 28 May 2028 12:00:00 UTC";

  //Display amount of performed sessions
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getCookieVal();
}
//Display 0 when no sessions have been performed yet
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "getCookieVal()";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
myAudio = new Audio('someSound.ogg'); 
myAudio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false);
myAudio.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the cookie is deleted when the browser is closed. You can add a date to the cookie to set expiracy far in the future, so it will not be deleted:

```
document.cookie = "totalSessionsJ=0; expires=Sun, 28 May 2028 12:00:00 UTC";
```

To read the value:

```
function getCookieVal() {
    var cookieValue = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)totalSessionsJ\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
    return cookieValue;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I am just having difficulty getting to change the value of the cookie now.